# StackView not appearing even after setting autoresize to false

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupLabels()
    }

fileprivate func setupLabels() {
        let greenView = UIView()
        greenView.backgroundColor = .green

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [greenView])

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40),
            stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 40),
            stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 40)
            ])

}
```

My stackview is not showing up. I thought that it might be hiding behind the VC view, but when I set the color to clear, there's nothing in the view. Is there something I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: Your `UIStackView` appears fine, it just contains nothing - you never set a frame for  `greenView `, so that frame is zero. Also, you are not supposed to set size constraints for `UIStackView` - it's supposed to resize itself based on the content.

Comment: wrong constraint. top = view.top and bottom = view.top????

Comment: that was it!! But now the green fills the entire view and none of the constraints except the left one are working.

Comment: aahh wait. I got it. I have to make the left and bottom constraints negative. Thanks for the help!